# xpath search for divs where the id contains specific text

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

On my HTML page I have forty divs but I only want one div.

Using agility pack to search and get all the divs with Ids I use this XPath:

```
"//div[@id]"
```

But how do I search for divs with Ids where the id contains the text "test" like so:

```
<div id="outerdivtest1></div>"
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Use the `contains` function:

```
//div[contains(@id,'test')]
```

Answer (score 4):

I've used this with for the CSS class:

```
//div[@class = 'atom']
```

I assume it's similar with id's.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the xpath

```
//div[@contains(@id,'test')]
```

If you want to use the first occurrence, it works fine but if it's not the first occurrence you have to go with different xpath specific to the particular element.

Comment: If you wanted the second occurrence of that element, the following xpath would work:

`(//div[@contains(@id,'test')])[2]`

Comment: `@contains` does not have the `@`

Answer (score -1):

For example if you want first selection "id" is like that
(//*[@id="numberIdentify"])//following::*//a[contains(text(),'V ')]