# Using Xpath Contains ID?

Tags: dom, xpath, scrapy

```
<div id="content-body-14269002-17290547">
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
</div>
```

I Need To Select Everything in `id = "content-body*"`

content-body changes on every Page, May Be Need to **Use Wildcards** ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xpath search for divs where the id contains specific text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176723/xpath-search-for-divs-where-the-id-contains-specific-text)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Probably [xpath search for divs where the id contains specific text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176723/xpath-search-for-divs-where-the-id-contains-specific-text) Duplicate

Anyways,

**For IDs**

```
//div[contains(@id,"content-body")]//p #to Select all Paragraphs 

//div[contains(@id,"content-body")]//p//text() # To Select all text in Paragraphs
```

**For Classes**

```
//*[contains(@class,"content-body")//p
//div[contains(@class,"content-body")]//p//text()
```

**For Class in Class**

```
//*[contains(@class,"content-body") and contains(@class,"another-sub-content-body")]//p//text()
```

Hope it Helps !!!

Answer (score 3):

```
//div[contains(@id, "content-body")]
```

This means `content-body` in `content-body-14269002-17290547`

Normally, this will works.

Better:

```
//div[starts-with(@id, "content-body")]
```

This means the id attribute's value is started with `content-body`

Comment: You missed the closing round bracket